# Set width dynamically in LinearLayout

Tags: android, dynamic, android-linearlayout

I created a custom seekbar preference using this tutorial http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html. I would like to dynamically adjust the width of the seekbar based on the users screen size. Specifically, here is the code from the tutorial that sets the width

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

I would like the values of 80 and 30 to by dynamic. Would using a different layout be better?

---

Edit: Found the following solution which seems to be going in the right direction but isn't perfect yet.

```
DisplayMetrics size = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size.widthPixels - 350, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

This still uses the hard coded 350.

Comment: I suggest you read "Lessons" from this manual
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: The tutorial does not use an XML layout file to create the preference view. Instead it does it programmatically. The manual you linked to does uses an XML layout file. I'm not sure how to do it programmatically.

Comment: The the conclusion from a tutorial is that you don't need to adjust layout width. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically set the width of the three items that make up the seekbar (params1, params2, param3 in the tutorial) based on the width of the user's screen. I about got it in my last edit but still need to figure out params2.

Comment: My previous edit using DisplayMetrics seems to be the best I can come up with. I'm not sure how to attract attention to my question and get an answer here on SO.

Comment: it seems someone needs to revise your layout and your code to understand what is your goal and to find a better way to solve it. You'd better post layout xml and logic that changes and screenshots with results. Because like this it's hard to understand your particular case. But anyway I doubt I will find some free time to help you out. If someone comes across better post more information about it.

Comment: All layout, logic, and screen shots are included in the tutorial I linked to.